# Print the JSON response from GET request in Finagle

Tags: scala, rest, future, finagle, twitter-finagle

I am trying to do a GET request and print the JSON response that I get back. The JSON response should look like this.

```
{
    "request_status": "Success",
    "workflow_step": "End"
}
```

Here's my code:

```
handle(GetStatus) { args: GetStatus.Args =>
    val client: Service[http.Request, http.Response] =
      Http.client.withTlsWithoutValidation.newService("idm-preprod-fe1.twitter.biz:80")
    val request = http.Request(
      http.Method.Get,
      "/plugin/rest/groupmanagement/getStatus/Create Group Request for mygroup (1638800484991)")
    request.host = "idm-preprod-fe1.twitter.biz"
    Future.value(GetStatusResponse(Option(client(request).toString)))
  }
```

Now when my client sends the request to the server, I want to print the JSON but the format that I am getting is. Can someone please guide me as how to achieve this.

```
Promise@1589131174(state=Transforming(WaitQueue(size=1),Promise@1823443423(state=Transforming(WaitQueue(size=1),Promise@859399396(state=Transforming(WaitQueue(size=4),Promise@1441370332(state=Transforming(WaitQueue(size=2),Promise@1459834(state=Transforming(WaitQueue(size=2),Promise@156947070(state=Transforming(WaitQueue(size=1),Promise@1739595981(state=Transforming(WaitQueue(size=1),Promise@273198152(state=Transforming(WaitQueue(size=1),Promise@478329071(state=Transforming(WaitQueue(size=2),Promise@1175786031(state=Transforming(WaitQueue(size=1),Promise@1749285277(state=Transforming(WaitQueue(size=1),Promise@1733124454(state=Transforming(WaitQueue(size=1),Promise@1257379837(state=Transforming(WaitQueue(size=1),Promise@1192050340(state=Transforming(WaitQueue(size=1),Promise@1114225943(state=Transforming(WaitQueue(size=1),Promise@1417620904(state=Transforming(WaitQueue(size=1),Promise@1638767611(state=Interruptible(WaitQueue(size=2),<function1>))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

`client(request)` is giving you a `Future[http.Response]`: it represents a response that will be available some time in the future.

You cannot use `toString()` on it directly because it's a `Future` and also because even if it was not a `Future` it would be a `Response`, which is a whole HTTP response, not only the body.

I'd recommend reading more about how `Future` works and how to use it.

In your case, you should do something like following (*pseudo code as I'm not familiar with Twitter's `Future`*):

```scala
client(request).map { httpResponse =>
  val responseBody = httpResponse.body
  GetStatusResponse(Option(responseBody))
}
```